# Using pattern matching in python, extract a table from .lua file

Tags: python, regex

I have a .lua file where there are stored tables in this format:

```
["f@someFaction - someServer@guildVaults"] = {
    ["someStr1"] = {
        ["someStr2"] = 7,
        ["someStr3"] = 2
    }
    ["someStr4"] = {
        ["someStr5"] = 7,
        ["someStr6"] = 2
    }
}
```

Basically there can be any number of nested tables. I know the names of the initial table that I'm looking to extract, however, I have trouble extracting the subsequent table.

```
with open("somePath", "rb") as file:
    f = file.read()

pattern = r"\[\"f@[a-zA-z]+ - [a-zA-z]+@guildVaults\"\] = \{[ \t\n]*"
guildVaults = re.findall(pattern, f)

for guild in guildVaults:
    print guild
```

Results:

```
["f@Alliance - Thunderhorn@guildVaults"] = {
["f@Alliance - Proudmoore@guildVaults"] = {
["f@Alliance - Kazzak@guildVaults"] = {
["f@Horde - Draenor@guildVaults"] = {
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:
example of the .lua file here:
http://www.pastefile.com/Tx2LVD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate *flags*. Also, I would extract everything until a single `{` is present in a line (assuming all of your tables are similarly formatted):

```
pattern = r"\[\"f@[a-zA-z]+ - [a-zA-z]+@guildVaults\"\] = ({.*?^}$)"
guildVaults = re.findall(pattern, data, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

for guild in guildVaults:
    print(guild)
```

For the provided input data, it prints:

```
{
    ["someStr1"] = {
        ["someStr2"] = 7,
        ["someStr3"] = 2
    }
    ["someStr4"] = {
        ["someStr5"] = 7,
        ["someStr6"] = 2
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that yields an empty result. Here is a screenshot on how it is formatted: https://i.gyazo.com/8af990c1cb1711fc40db4c7a1adb74fe.png. Here is another screenshot with the first guild hidden: https://i.gyazo.com/3353d4d40e44e547be7b45a882373b04.png

Comment: I've edited the OP and have put a direct sample data there (.lua file)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to convert the lua to python, then exec the result and get native python objects.

1. Detect the top-level lines: `["f@someFaction - someServer@guildVaults"] = {`

and extract all text until the ending } .

2. In this text, remove all square brackets, replace all "}" to "}," and = to :.
3. Prepend some variable name for the result, for example `foo = {`
   and add } at end.

You will get:

```
foo = {
    "someStr1" : {
        "someStr2" : 7,
        "someStr3" : 2
    },
    "someStr4" : {
        "someStr5" : 7,
        "someStr6" : 2
    }
}
```

Now, this can be manipulated in Python.

Comment: Indeed, that is the end goal. Problem is the 'extract all text until ending }' part.

Comment: Apply some heuristic :) LIke, } alone in postion 1. Or in the hard way, count opening and closing curly braces.

Comment: Well the reason why I want to use pattern matching is because it should be possible to extract the text here: ["f@someFaction - someServer@guildVaults"] = { ... text to extract ... }. However, I was unable to make it work and even with @alecxe's solution, it still does not work - hence I provided an actual file to do some testing on.

Comment: Maybe this can be done with some advanced regexp fu. Perhaps I'd combine both things: simply loop thru the file + simple pattern matching for searching the 1st and last line of each chunk/variable. And be done with it.

Comment: I've realised that the mistake was in using 'rb' instead of 'r' when opening the file. It works according to alecxe's suggestion now (with some minor tweaks).